# Integer to double conversion

Tags: c++, templates, integer, double

how can I convert integer to double? I have this code and the result of it is `15`, not `15.45` that's because the program takes the first number in as the type of the result, in this program that's integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < class T1 , class T2 >

T1 smaller ( T1 a, T2 b ){
    return (a<b?a:b); 
}

int main(){
    int x = 98;
    double y = 15.45;

    cout << smaller( x , y ) << endl; 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What problems do you have?

Comment: Umm, neither `15` nor `15.34` are the correct result. The correct result would be `15.45`.

Comment: I wrote the wrong number, not it's the result of the program 15 instead of 15.45

Comment: @T.C. That should be posted as an answer (with a note that it requires C++11, and that without C++11, Antonio's response is about the best you can do).

Answer (score 2):

It's because your return type is templated on the type of the first input parameter, that in this case is integer.

You should have the same type for both input, and the output, and choose explicitly the type to be used in your function. For example:

```
template < class T >

T smaller ( T a, T b ){
    return (a<b?a:b); 
}

int main {
    int x = 98;
    double y = 15.45;

//    cout << smaller( x , y ) << endl; //This wouldn't compile. It would compile if x and y had the same type.
//    cout << smaller<int>( x , y ) << endl; //This would still return 15
    cout << smaller<double>( x , y ) << endl; 

}
```

As user2079303 mentions, the function that you are trying to implement is very similar to the std::min function available in the standard library.

Comment: yes yes, i understand that.. i just want to know whats the solution of this problem withaut that i change the numbers order

Comment: It might be useful to mention that this function already exists in the standard library with the name `std::min`. Except, the standard version has references instead of copies as arguments and return value which is relevant if the template parameter is more than a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use trailing return types together with `decltype` and `std::decay` (alternatively, `std::common_type`):

```
template < class T1 , class T2 >
auto smaller ( T1 a, T2 b ) -> typename std::decay<decltype(a<b?a:b)>::type {
    return (a<b?a:b); 
}
```

The `decay` is necessary to ensure that the function returns by value. Since you are taking the argument by value, you can't return a reference.

In C++14, you can use return type deduction:

```
template < class T1 , class T2 >
auto smaller ( T1 a, T2 b ) {
    return (a<b?a:b); 
}
```

Pre-C++11, you can write a mightily complicated `promotion_traits` class with lots of specializations to determine the appropriate return type and return `typename promotion_traits<T1, T2>::type`, or you can do what Antonio suggests and template `smaller` on one template parameter instead, in which case it becomes `std::min` but passing by value instead of const reference.

Answer (score 0):

in your function call, try casting x as a double.

```
(double)x //or
static_cast<double>(x)
```

Comment: can i do this as an if, that i can use it also when float, or long comes

Comment: @Lila you can do it regardless. It is safe to case to a `double` even if the number is already a `double`.